# TFS C# API: Workspace.PendAdd silently fails

Tags: c#, .net, windows, tfs, windows-server-2008

[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.PendAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139339)

For some reason, whenever I call the PendAdd method from the TFS API, it executes with no exceptions yet fails to mark any files as added in my workspace. However, Calling PendEdit consistently works as expected. I've verified that the account used both has permission to add within TFS and has full control Windows permissions on the files in question.

Any ideas?

My code (for debugging, I'm attempting four variations on input to the PendAdd method):

```
public bool AddFile( string filePath, out string status, bool isRecursive = false )
{
    Workspace workspace = GetWorkspace( out status );
    if( workspace == null )
    {
        return false;
    }

    workspace.PendAdd( filePath, isRecursive );

    status = "Success";
    return true;
}

public bool CheckOutFile( string filePath, out string status )
{
    Workspace workspace = GetWorkspace( out status );
    if( workspace == null )
    {
        return false;
    }

    workspace.PendEdit( filePath );

    status = "Success";
    return true;
}
...
string status;

// $/Solution/.../foo.cs (non-recursive)
if( TFS.AddFile("$/Solution" + Regex.Split(target, "Solution")[1].Replace('\\', '/'), out status) == false )
{
    throw new Exception( "TFS Add failed: " + status );
}

// $/Solution/.../ (recursive)
if( TFS.AddFile("$/Solution" + Regex.Split(target.Substring(0, target.LastIndexOf('\\')), "Solution")[1].Replace('\\', '/'), out status, true) == false )
{
    throw new Exception( "TFS Add failed: " + status );
}

// Calls PendEdit with C:\TFS\Solution\...\foo.cs; this works
if( TFS.CheckOutFile(target, out status) == false )
{
    throw new Exception( "TFS Checkout failed: " + status );
}

// C:\TFS\Solution\...\foo.cs (non-recursive)
if( TFS.AddFile(target, out status) == false )
{
    throw new Exception( "TFS Add failed: " + status );
}

// C:\TFS\Solution\...\ (recursive)
if( TFS.AddFile(target.Substring(0, target.LastIndexOf('\\')), out status, true) == false )
{
    throw new Exception( "TFS Add failed: " + status );
}
...
private Workspace GetWorkspace( out string status )
{
    Workspace[] workspaces = _versionControlServer.QueryWorkspaces( null, _versionControlServer.AuthorizedUser, Environment.MachineName );

    if( workspaces.Length != 1 )
    {
        status  = "You must have exactly 1 local workspace to promote code.";
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        status  = "You have exactly 1 local workspace.";
    }

    return workspaces[0];
}
```

Comment: What is the code for `GetWorkspace`?  What do your workspace mappings look like?

Comment: Just added it. I have one workspace with two projects checked out and only one project being actively modified by the code. The workspace is never modified outside of this code.

Comment: *one workspace with two projects mapped (both projects being in the same solution). To clarify, the workspace/mappings was set up with Visual Studio and has been used by Visual Studio to check in code, but isn't used by anything other than this code on an ongoing basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is odd, but I made a change to allow multiple users to add or edit files through this controller (rather than one hardcoded user) and create a new workspace for each user when necessary, and now everything's working as originally intended. This is pretty odd, considering that nothing that should have been related to this behaviour was modified in any significant way.

I'm not fully convinced that this isn't a bug / that I hadn't previously been hitting some edge case in the code, but as long as my project works (which it does as of now) I'm not really concerned either way.

[Relevant Microsoft Connect thread](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762789/tfs-c-api-workspace-pendadd-silently-fails) (in case this does turn out to be a problem with TFS and is later resolved).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (even with the MSDN sample [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130331)), but invoking [`Workstation.EnsureUpdateWorkspaceInfoCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139687(v=vs.120).aspx) before calling PendAdd solved it for me.

Listening to [NonFatalErrors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.nonfatalerror(v=vs.120).aspx) can give you quite useful hints for such issues.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you! I had spend 3 days woking in that.

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced this strange behaviour. I could fix it by creating the file on my filesystem **BEFORE** adding it to sourceControl.

Otherwise, it will fail silently.